# Bokeh slider to control slice of data presented on axes with static range?

Tags: widget, slider, bokeh

I would like to use Bokeh to plot a slice of a pandas series object on a figure with static range.  I would like to control the position of the slice within the series object using a slider. The slice width would be static.

As an example, if I were presented a 2 second slice of a velocity time series, the slider would control the "timeStart" value that indicated the start of the window.  The x values of the timeseries presented would range from timeStart to timeStart+2.

This is a part of a larger problem, and so I have 2 additional constraints:

- The axes range values on the figure are static.
- The data must be precalculated (i.e., data is not generated by a parameteric equation that can be used in the callback function).

I've pasted an example of my current efforts below.  I am using a parametric function for the purpose of the example, but again, the end result must use precalculate data.

```
import bokeh.plotting as bkP
import bokeh.models as bkM
from bokeh.io import vform
import numpy as np
bkP.output_notebook()

from bokeh.io import vform

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
y = np.sin(x)

source = bkP.ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x,y=y))#,fr=np.zeros(len(x))))

plot = bkP.figure(x_range=(0,100),y_range=(-1,1), plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = bkM.CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""

    var data = source.get('data');
    var start = frame.get('value')

    oldX = data['x']
    oldY = data['y']

    for (i = -10; i < 10; i++) {
        x[i] = fr+i
        y[i] = y[fr+i]
    }

    source.trigger('change');

""")

fr_slider = bkM.Slider(start=0, end=len(x), value=0, step=1, #
                    title="frame", callback=callback)

callback.args["frame"] = fr_slider

layout = bkP.hplot(
    plot,
    vform(fr_slider),
)

bkP.show(layout)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use two data source, one for drawing, one to hold the whole data. In the callback of the slider, copy data from the second source to the first source:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, vform
from bokeh.plotting import figure, Figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider, CustomJS
import numpy as np

output_notebook()

x = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0, 100, 2000))
y = np.sin(x*10) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=2000)
fig = Figure(plot_height=400)

mask = (x > 0) & (x < 2)

source1 = ColumnDataSource(data={"x":x[mask], "y":y[mask]}, id="source1")
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data={"x":x, "y":y}, id="source2")
line = fig.line(x="x", y="y", source=source1)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(s1=source1, s2=source2), code="""
var d1 = s1.get("data");
var d2 = s2.get("data");
var start = cb_obj.get("value");
var s = Bokeh._.findIndex(d2["x"], function(v){return v > start;});
var e = Bokeh._.findIndex(d2["x"], function(v){return v > start + 2;});
d1["x"] = [];
d1["y"] = [];
for(i=s;i<=e;i++){
    d1["x"].push(d2["x"][i]);
    d1["y"].push(d2["y"][i]);
}
s1.trigger("change");
""")
slider = Slider(start=0, end=100, step=2, callback=callback)
show(vform(slider, fig))
```

or you can show the whole data and change the x range in callback:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, vform
from bokeh.plotting import figure, Figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider, CustomJS
import numpy as np

output_notebook()

x = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0, 100, 2000))
y = np.sin(x*10) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=2000)
fig = Figure(plot_height=400, x_range=(0, 2))

source = ColumnDataSource(data={"x":x, "y":y})
line = fig.line(x="x", y="y", source=source)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(x_range=fig.x_range), code="""
var start = cb_obj.get("value");
x_range.set("start", start);
x_range.set("end", start+2);
""")
slider = Slider(start=0, end=100, step=2, callback=callback)
show(vform(slider, fig))
```

Comment: where can I find Bokeh._.findIndex? My program works fine if I just set e equal to start and s equal to 0, but when I try to use this findIndex function, it breaks (my plot does not update)